# Sending NSDictionary to webservice

Tags: iphone, web-services, nsdictionary

In my iphone app,I am trying to send an NSDictionary to a java webservice. In the webservice when the parameter is kept as hashmap,it gets into the the method accessed;But doesnot  get the parameters(shown as null).
Where am I going wrong?Pls help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show some code or explain exactly how you send the NSDictionary to your java web service and how do you proceed with the dictionary on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [SBJSON](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/) library, that will give you a JSON representation of your NSDictionary. JSON is widely used as a object representation format over HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

How can you send a NSDictionary to a web service.... its not possible.
You have to convert your dictionary object into json format or some structure or as parameters to web service etc and then post it.

 The object of NSDictionary may not be same as that of "HashMap" in java.